# Rails query producing incorrect result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables in a rails application as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150603200530) do  
  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "source"
    t.integer "target"
    t.integer "value"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "group"
  end
end
```

One User has many relationships (User.id=relationship.source).

I have populated the database as follows with a populate.rake file

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Erase and fill database"
  task :populate => :environment do
    require 'populator'
    require 'faker'

    [User, Relationship].each(&:delete_all)



   User.populate 5 do |user|
      user.name = Populator.words(1..3).titleize
      user.group =1..5
    Relationship.populate 1..5 do |relationship|
        relationship.source = rand(1..5)
        relationship.target = rand(1..5)
        relationship.value = rand(1..5)
        end
    end
  end
```

I am trying to get a database query result into a specific format for json (the actual json formatting is done elsewhere) and this requires name and group to be under 'node' and source, target and value under 'links'. In my user model I have queried the database as follows.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships

  def self.including_relationships
    User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.source").select("users.name, users.`group`, relationships.source, relationships.target, relationships.value").each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |a, obj| 


      obj['nodes'] << a.slice('name','group')
      obj['links'] << a.slice('source', 'target', 'value')
    end
  end
end
```

This produces usable json output. The query before the each_with_object part works fine and gives me the expected results in rails console. However when I run it in the brower, it produces an incorrect number of names.  I think the problem must lie in the way the array works as the query is fine but I am getting too many nodes and links. The query output from the rails console is here:

[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]

The json output I am currently getting is here:

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"A Voluptatem Quo","group":2},{"name":"Debitis Ut","group":1},{"name":"A Voluptatem Quo","group":2},{"name":"Eos","group":1},{"name":"Eos","group":1},{"name":"Debitis Ut","group":1},{"name":"Debitis Ut","group":1},{"name":"Placeat Aliquam Cumque","group":5},{"name":"Placeat Aliquam Cumque","group":5},{"name":"Placeat Aliquam Cumque","group":5},{"name":"Debitis Ut","group":1},{"name":"Error In","group":4},{"name":"Eos","group":1},{"name":"A Voluptatem Quo","group":2}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":1,"value":4},{"source":4,"target":1,"value":4},{"source":1,"target":3,"value":4},{"source":3,"target":5,"value":2},{"source":3,"target":5,"value":4},{"source":4,"target":1,"value":5},{"source":4,"target":5,"value":1},{"source":5,"target":5,"value":2},{"source":5,"target":5,"value":1},{"source":5,"target":3,"value":5},{"source":4,"target":4,"value":3},{"source":2,"target":2,"value":5},{"source":3,"target":1,"value":5},{"source":1,"target":5,"value":2}]}
```

Comment: what's the foreign key in the `relationships` table ?

Comment: That you need to mention in your `belongs_to` as `.., foreign_key: source`

Comment: I have done this. As I have said in the question the problem is not the query output which is fine, it is in what the hash loop does. It is the hash that is producing too many nodes -the part of the statement as here: each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |a, obj|

Comment: How is the output different than expected? I don't see anything wrong with the loop. Show us a small sample of what's returned vs what was expected

Comment: Having looked at this it must be the query that is incorrect. What I want is the relationship table result and one 'name' and 'group' from the User table for each relationship.source. At the moment I am getting a repeated name from the User table for each row of the relationship table. This must be a problem with the join I am using in the query?